# Opening a new tab on Google Chrome Extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

This is my background.html file, It works fine when opening in current tab but I want it to open in new tab, what am I doing wrong?

```
<html>
<head>
<script>
  // Called when the user clicks on the browser action.
  chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function(tab) {
    var action_url = "javascript:location.href='http://www.reddit.com/submit?url='+encodeURIComponent(location.href)+'&title='+encodeURIComponent(document.title)";
    chrome.tabs.create(tab.id, {url: action_url}, function(tab));
  });
</script>
</head>
</html>
```

Comment: Make sure your action_url starts with: `http://` or `https://`

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You should read the `chrome.tabs.create` [documentation](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/tabs/#method-create) again. You are passing it invald parameters. You are also using `location` which is from the `background.html` document not the webpage document the code is expecting instead of the `tab` parameter passed to the `chrome.browserAction.onClicked` listener.

```
<html>
<head>
<script>
  // Called when the user clicks on the browser action.
  chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function(tab) {
    var action_url = "http://www.reddit.com/submit?url=" + encodeURIComponent(tab.href) + '&title=' + encodeURIComponent(tab.title);
    chrome.tabs.create({ url: action_url });
  });
</script>
</head>
</html>
```

Comment: where to get id of tab?

Answer (score 2):

You can try this

```
<html>
...
<body>
    <script>
    function createTab() {
        chrome.tabs.create({url: "http://www.stackoverflow.com"});
    }
    </script>
    <a href="#" onclick="createTab();">Create a new tab</a>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: No I don't want it like this, I actually want the new tab to be created as soon as the icon is pressed.

Comment: @Jeff This is just an example. I wanted to show you that you don't need to write the `chrome.tabs.create` command so complicated. Try to use this instead. Even though I'm not good at JavaScript the `var action_url` seems odd to me... Check JavaScript console for possible errors.

Comment: Note that in Manifest 2.0 the default [Content Security Policy](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/contentSecurityPolicy) prohibits inline JavaScript.

Answer (score 1):

```
<html>
 <head>
  <script type="text/javascript">
   window.master = ({
     newtab: function(url, callback) {
       callback = callback === true ? (function() { this.close(); }) : callback;

       try {
         chrome.tabs.create({
           url: url
         });

         if(typeof callback === "function") { callback.call(this, url); }
       } catch(e) {
         /* Catch errors due to possible permission issues. */
       }
     },

     link: function(event, close) {
       event = event ? event : window.event;
       event.preventDefault();
       this.newtab(event.href, close);
     },

     close: function() { window.self.close(); }
   });
  </script>
 </head>

 <body>
  <!-- Usage is simple:

        HTML:
         <a href="http://example.com/" onclick="master.link(event)" />

        JavaScript:
         master.newtab("http://example.com/", true);
  -->
 </body>
</html>
```

If you insist on using a popup and want it to close as soon as it is opened, then use what is above. Simply add the link string and a `true` boolean to the `master.newtab` function to have it open the new tab and then close the popup.

If you change your mind about closing the popup, you can replace the `true` boolean with a function to execute if the new tab was created without any errors. You can also use the `master.link` function for calling the `master.newtab` function from an anchor element.

The best thing about using Chrome Extensions is you never have to worry about support issues! :D

Comment: This doesn't seem to work, when clicking the icon it is just unresponsive I'm using the reddit submit bookmarklet js.